# Enterprise patterns in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm studying enterprise patterns to use with .NET, I read a lot of theory but I don't have sample code to study.

I would like to know if there is any open source project available there uses these patterns so I can have a clear idea of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not an open source project you may find some good samples in this book: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321268202/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202) "Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET"

Answer (score 1):

There are many open sources project or .NET frameworks (whose source can be viewed using Reflector) which use design patterns.

You can look at the sources for **ASP NET MVC** (source is freely downloadable), **WCF and Entity Framework** (as I said using *Reflector*). On open source projects, you can look at **NHibernate**, **NServiceBus** and **OpenRasta**.

Comment: Note that viewing decompiled code using Reflector could be illegal in some jurisdictions.